# Calculus (advanced integration)

Tags: calculus, integration

Compute

$\int (5^x+2e^{5 \ln x})dx$

The $5\ln x$ part confuses me.

So far I have $5^x/\ln 5\:\:$

Comment: hint : $a\ln b =  \ln b^a$  and  $e^{\ln x}  = x$

Answer (score 2):

$\int (5^x+2e^{5 \ln x})dx=\int (e^{x\operatorname{ln}5}+2x^{5})dx=\frac{1}{\operatorname{ln}5}e^{x\operatorname{ln}5}+\frac13x^6+C$

Comment: Can you explain how you did this

Comment: @usermath did you somehow cancel out e and ln in $2x^5$?

Comment: fixed now..sorry

Comment: sorry again..extremely sorry..fixed..

Comment: I still don't understand how you did it

Comment: Which part don't you understand?

Comment: The first part to the second part

Comment: It is quickly explained in the posted answer. Since $5=e^{\ln 5}$, we have $5^x=(e^{\ln 5})^x=e^{5\ln x}$. Now integrate by substitution. For the other half, we have $e^{5\ln x}=(e^{\ln x})^5=x^5$.

Comment: Where does it say $(e^{lnx})^5$

Comment: @AndréNicolas‏‏

Comment: In general, $(a^b)^c=a^{bc}$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas yeah but why is it $(e^{5lnx})$ instead of $(e^{xln5})$

Comment: We are looking at $e^{5\ln x}$. This is $e^{(\ln x)(5)}$. Which is $(e^{\ln x})^5$. But $e^{\ln x}=x$.

Comment: I'm sorry. Can we just start over

Comment: @AndréNicolas actually just got it. just had to give it another look